# Styling arrow in Select Box

Tags: css, frontend

I'm creating a dropdown menu box and arrow. It looks good except one thing. I used `:focus` so when user is on select the box, it will turn to green. Yes, box is turning to green but when I do the same thing for arrow icon, it is not changing. Can someone help me with this? 
All help will be appreciated.

I have searched some solution on the internet but could not fix the problem.

```css
input[type=text],
input[type=tel],
input[type=email] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #A9A9A9;
}


/* user input and dropdown turning to green color when active */

input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=tel]:focus,
input[type=email]:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #42AC82;
}


/* dropdown box styling */

select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #A9A9A9;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.select-container {
  position: relative;
}

select:-moz-focusring {
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}

.select-arrow {
  color: #A9A9A9;
  right: 0px;
  top: 7px;
  width: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

select:required:invalid {
  color: gray;
}

select[value=""][disabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='col col-1-of-4'>Is desicion maker?<br>
    <div class="select-container">
      <span class="select-arrow fa fa-caret-down" style="font- 
              size: 1.5em;"></span>
      <select name="options" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option
        </option>
        <option value="1">yes</option>
        <option value="2">no</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div
```

Comment: Your `<span>` tag is outside of the setlect and only select seem to have a focus property. Try adding a css block with `.select-arrow:focus` :)

Comment: Share your code with jsfiddle.

Comment: @JonasJohansson Yes, I did add `.select-arrow:focus` but it did not change :-/ This was what I meant in my question `:focus`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're not seeing the arrow color change is that the arrow icon is not a children or next sibling of `select` element and there's no CSS selector for previous/ parent element. The way I see it you have two options there:

1) Move you arrow icon after select:

```
          <select name="options" required>
             <option value="" disabled selected>Select an 
             option</option>
             <option value="1">yes</option>
             <option value="2">no</option>
          </select>
          <span class="select-arrow fa fa-caret-down" style="font- 
      size: 1.5em;"></span>
```

Which should you allow to use `+` (next sibling) selector

```
select:focus + .select arrow { color: #42AC82 }
```

2) Use JS to detect select element focus and toggle class `select-container` element what would allow you to style all child elements as you need

Answer (score 0):

Try add some of your css like this part:

```
input[type=text]:focus ~ span ,
input[type=tel]:focus ~ span ,
input[type=email]:focus ~ span ,
select:focus ~ span ,
textarea:focus ~ span {
    color: red;
}


And transfer your span with icon after select tag like this: 



    <select name="options" required>
         <option value="" disabled selected>Select an option</option>
         <option value="1">yes</option>                     
         <option value="2">no</option>
         </select>
         <span class="select-arrow fa fa-caret-down" style="font-size: 1.5em;">
       </span>
```

Comment: having other elements than `option` as children of `select` element is not a valid markup

Comment: span is not children of select dude.

Comment: ah- my bad, I completely missed your closing tag :)

Comment: That's okay bro :D